# FreeBSD ee editor - can't type numbers

Tags: unix, freebsd

So I am using ee editor in FreeBSD 8.1 box. I cannot type numbers though. I open a file with:

```
ee file
```

I start writing letters which works fine but when I press a number on my keyboard (1, 2, 3 etc) I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I cannot type a number.

Comment: Specify, in your question, **which** number keys you are using.  Most PC keyboards have at least two distinct sets of keys for generating numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess: You are using PuTTY to connect to the server, and *ee* has requested it to enable "application keypad" mode, in which the numpad sends special sequences instead of numbers, which *ee* then misinterprets.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd> to toggle back to "normal" mode.
- It can be disabled permanently under *Terminal → Features → Disable application keypad mode*.